# How to access values in XML

Tags: java, xml

To access the values id1 & id2 im iterating over every value in the XML and if I find a tag named id1 or id2 I read its value into a variable. Is there a better method of reading the values id1 & id2 ?

```xml
<begin>
  <total>1</total>
  <values>
    <factor>
      <base>test</base>
      <id1>id1</id1>
      <id2>id2</id2>
      <val>val2</val>
      <newval>val1</newval>
    </factor>
  </values>
</begin>
```

Comment: if all you interested is querying certain elements, [xpath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/) is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use XPath, you can extract values directly from the Document object.  In your case, the XPath to get to `id1` would be `/begin/id1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Java API for XML Processing](http://jaxp.java.net/). It's a very robust way of dealing with XML in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Use a SAX parser and store the text emitted after the "id1" start element as the id1 value and the text after the "id2" start element as the id2 value.

For example:

```java
public static List<String> getIds(InputStream xmlStream) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
  final List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
  SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
  saxParser.parse(xmlStream, new DefaultHandler() {
    boolean getChars = false;
    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
      if ("id1".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) getChars = true;
      if ("id2".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) getChars = true;
    }
    public void characters(char cs[], int start, int len) throws SAXException {
      if (getChars) {
        ids.add(new String(cs, start, len));
        getChars = false;
      }
    }
  });
  return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JDOM for doing this:

```
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.build("test.xml");
        String id1 = doc.getRootElement().getChild("values").getChild("factor").getChild("id1").getValue();
        System.out.println(id1);
        String id2 = doc.getRootElement().getChild("values").getChild("factor").getChild("id2").getValue();
        System.out.println(id2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use any library that supports XPath. [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) is currently my favorite, but there are plenty out there.